# How to find jquery element in jquery results?

Tags: jquery

**Terminology**

My terminology may be imperfect so here I try to explain what I mean by "results" or "elements" and I use these words as synonyms.

$("iframe") returns object which contains results like

```
[0] JQuery object ... (iframe #0)
[1] JQuery object ... (iframe #1)
```

In this code I am trying to work with these results (children or elements). I am not speaking about nested elements of iframe, but about the iframes only.

**Description**

I have created some function to filter results of $("iframe"). I need to create function to "invert" the results. So I will work with the results of $("iframe") which are not found by the function `myfunction`.

My problem is that I don't know How to identify each result or iframe element in the Variable `iframes`? I know that `iframe in iframes` is wrong - I cannot use `in` because it searches for `key in array` or object. But I need to find exact element in the variable iframes...

```
   var jif = $("iframe");
    var iframes = jif.filter(myfunction);
    jif.each(
      function( k, iframe, iframes) {
         if ( !(iframe in iframes) )
             iframe.remove();
    });
```

so instead of the part: `if ( !(iframe in iframes) )` I need to get:
if jquery **element** is **not in the** jquery **iframes** collection object.

Sorry but I don't know how to explain it better

Comment: Your question is still as unclear as your previous one. It sounds like an X-Y problem. It would be better if you told us what you are actually *trying to achieve* instead of what is wrong with the method you're currently attempting.

Comment: Perhaps look at the .not() selector?

Comment: Well, the first method was to find some iframes which contains some elements.. In contrary the new method should exclude the previous results of iframe and **get the rest of the iframes** which were not found by the previous function. The practical use for is that the first function can be used to apply styles to nested elements of iframe (like WYSIWYG Editor) and the second function can be used to remove all iframes which are not WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a specific element is inside some jquery collection you can use the `index` method:

```js
divs = $('div')
divsA = $('div.a')
divsB = $('div.b')

a = $('#a')
b = $('#b')
c = $('#c')
console.log("check if #a, #b, #c in divs")
console.log(divs.index(a) >= 0)
console.log(divs.index(b) >= 0)
console.log(divs.index(c) >= 0)

console.log("")
console.log("check if #a, #b, #c in divsA")
console.log(divsA.index(a) >= 0)
console.log(divsA.index(b) >= 0)
console.log(divsA.index(c) >= 0)

console.log("")
console.log("check if #a, #b, #c in divsB")
console.log(divsB.index(a) >= 0)
console.log(divsB.index(b) >= 0)
console.log(divsB.index(c) >= 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="a">Div with class a</div>
<div id="b" class="b">Div with class b</div>
<div id="c" class="a b">Div with class a and b</div>
```

> jQuery's `index` function will work also for elements which are not jquery, but also a regular dom elements:

```js
divsA = $('div.a')

a = document.getElementById('a')
b = document.getElementById('b')
console.log("check if #a, #b divsA")
console.log(divsA.index(a) >= 0)
console.log(divsA.index(b) >= 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="a">Div with class a</div>
<div id="b" class="b">Div with class a</div>
```

Regarding to the original question, this is the relevant code:

```
var jif = $("iframe");
var iframes = jif.filter(myfunction);
jif.each(
    function( k, iframe) {
        if ( !( iframes.index(iframe) >=0 ) ) {
            iframe.remove();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand it correctly, my solution is to change the `if` line to `if ( !( iframes.index(iframe) >=0 ) )`

Comment: Either that, or check if the `iframes.index(iframe) === -1`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Dekel's answer I have corrected the code:

```
var jif = $("iframe");
var iframes = jif.filter(myfunction);
jif.each(function(k, iframe) {
    if ( !( iframes.index(iframe) >= 0 ) )
        iframe.remove();
});
```

I have removed the 3rd argument `iframes` in anonymous function because it was undefined.

Comment: You should have kept the accepted answer as mine (You can also edit my answer and add the final solution there). Not cool!

Comment: I am not able to edit it I don't see neccessary html elements or their descriptions on this web-page. Sorry

Comment: Edited my answer, the code to fix your specific question was added there. I think you can accept again my answer, as it was the accepted answer originally.